# What is wrong with my Scheme using vector-set implementation?

Tags: vector, scheme, lisp, racket, normalization

I was wondering what I am doing wrong here with vector-set

```
(define foo0
  (lambda (vec)
    (let* ((newvec (vector vec))
           (l      (vector-length vec))
           (norm   (norm0 vec)))
      (do ((i 0(+ i 1)))
        ((= i l))
        (vector-set*! newvec  i (/(vector-ref vec i) norm))) newvec)))
```

I am trying to set each element of the vector to be divided by norm (an integer from another predicate).

The error I keep getting is

```
  vector-set!: index is out of range
  index: 1
  valid range: [0, 0]
  vector: '#(3/4)
```

So I am finding the first solution, however, the `newvec` gets reset to size 1, so the index goes out of range.

Comment: The formatting of your code is extremely strange. What went wrong?

Comment: @RainerJoswig it was my first post, my apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector` makes a mutable vector with the elements given as arguments, thus:

```
(vector 4)      ; a vector of one element
(vector 1 2 3)  ; a vector of 3 elements
```

SO lets say you need a 20 element vector that you are going to mutate and work with. Using `vector` is out of the question since then you would have to have 20 dummy arguments. Instead you use `make-vector` It takes two arguments, the size and an optional initial value for all the elements:

```
(make-vector 20 0)
; ==> #(0 0 ... 0), a vector of 20 elements, all 0
```

Now with the knowledge that you can get the length of the passed vector with `vector-length` you can pass that to `make-vector` to make a same size vector that you can copy values to to make a shallow copy. However you can do it much easier by using [`vector-copy`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/vectors.html?q=vector#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fvector..rkt%29._vector-copy%29%29)

Comment: what is the difference between a vector and a list ?

Comment: @naomik vectors are usually called arrays in other languages and are usually fixed length O(1) access while a list is a singly linked lists. Common Lisp have both vectors and arrays and the difference is that arrays can be dynamic size and multi dimensional.

Comment: @sylwester I used (vector-copy vec) instead of (vector vec) and that worked great! I now get the solution I want. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the second line of your program, you write `(vector vec)`. What does this evaluate to?